# Orderby meta_value only returns posts that have existing meta_key

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, sort

I have the following wp_query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'orderby' => 'meta_key',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key'=>'custom_author_name',
    'post_per_page'=>-1
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

echo $query->found_posts;
```

echo = 10 results because there are only 10 `news` posts with a `meta_key = custom_author_name`. But there are hundreds of `news` posts that don't have a post_meta row with that specific meta_key. Please notice, that there is no meta_query involved. No meta_value is assigned, because I am only trying to sort the posts by meta_key, and not filter by meta_value.

Shouldn't orderby select all posts? and just order them?

If so why is the result filtered? If the meta_key is not found, why not just use an empty string, or a match all?

If not, why not?

If I enter a meta_key to every news post (even if it's an empty string) then I get the expected result. But that seems like a whole lot of table rows that don't need to be there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated in @ambroseya's answer, its supposed to work like that.  Once you declare a meta query, even if you aren't looking for a specific value, it will only query posts with that meta key declared.  If you want to include all posts sort them by the meta key, use the following code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( 
            'key'=>'custom_author_name',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'           
        ),
        array( 
            'key'=>'custom_author_name',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'           
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page'=>-1
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

echo $query->found_posts;
```

What this does is use an advanced meta query that looks for posts that do and don't have that meta key declared.  Since the one with `EXISTS` is first, when you sort by `meta_value`, it'll use the first query.

Comment: This did not change the order at all for me, when I used `'orderby' => 'meta_value'`, it did change the order, but it had nothing to do with the actual meta field.

Answer (score 4):

I tried applying @Manny Fleurmond's answer and like @Jake I couldn't get it to work even after correcting the typo that `'orderby' => 'meta_key'` should be `'orderby' => 'meta_value'`. (And for completeness it should be `'posts_per_page'` not `'post_per_page'` but that doesn't affect the issue being looked at.)

If you look at the SQL query actually generated by @Manny Fleurmond's answer (having corrected the typos) this is what you get:

```
SELECT   wp_{prefix}_posts.* FROM wp_{prefix}_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_{prefix}_postmeta ON (wp_{prefix}_posts.ID = wp_{prefix}_postmeta.post_id AND wp_{prefix}_postmeta.meta_key = 'custom_author_name' )
LEFT JOIN wp_{prefix}_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_{prefix}_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
    wp_{prefix}_postmeta.post_id IS NULL 
    OR 
    mt1.meta_key = 'custom_author_name'
) AND wp_{prefix}_posts.post_type = 'news' AND
(wp_{prefix}_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_{prefix}_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_{prefix}_posts.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY wp_{prefix}_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_{prefix}_postmeta.meta_value ASC
```

This illustrates the way WP is parsing the query vars: it's creating a table for each meta_query clause, then figuring out how to join them and what to order by. The ordering would work fine if you were only using a single clause with `'compare' => 'EXISTS'`, but joining the second `'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'` clause with OR (as we must) messes up the ordering. The result is that LEFT JOIN is used to join both the first clause / table and the second clause / table - and the way WP puts everything together means that the table created using `'compare' => 'EXISTS'` is actually being populated with meta_values from ANY custom field, not just the `'custom_author_name'` field we are interested in. So I think ordering by that clause / table will only give the desired results if the particular post_type of 'news' only has a single custom field.

The solution that worked for my situation was to order by the other clause / table - the NOT EXISTS one. Seemingly counter-intuitive I know, but because of the way WP parses the query vars it is this table where `meta_value` is populated only by the custom field we are after.

(The only way I figured this out was by running the equivalent of this query for my case:

```
SELECT   wp_{prefix}_posts.ID, wp_{prefix}_postmeta.meta_value, mt1.meta_value FROM wp_{prefix}_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_{prefix}_postmeta ON (wp_{prefix}_posts.ID = wp_{prefix}_postmeta.post_id AND wp_{prefix}_postmeta.meta_key = 'custom_author_name' )
LEFT JOIN wp_{prefix}_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_{prefix}_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
    wp_{prefix}_postmeta.post_id IS NULL 
    OR 
    mt1.meta_key = 'custom_author_name'
) AND wp_{prefix}_posts.post_type = 'news' AND
(wp_{prefix}_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_{prefix}_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_{prefix}_posts.post_status = 'private')
ORDER BY wp_{prefix}_postmeta.meta_value ASC
```

All I've done is changed the columns being shown and removed the GROUP BY clause. This then showed me what was going on - that the postmeta.meta_value column was pulling in values from all meta_keys, while the mt1.meta_value column was pulling in only meta_values from the news custom field.)

**The Solution**

As @Manny Fleurmond says, it is the first clause that is used for the orderby, so the answer is just to swap the clauses round, giving this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( 
            'key' => 'custom_author_name',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'           
        ),
        array( 
            'key' => 'custom_author_name',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'           
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Alternatively you can make the clauses associative arrays and order by the corresponding key, like so:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'orderby' => 'not_exists_clause',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'exists_clause' => array( 
            'key' => 'custom_author_name',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'           
        ),
        'not_exists_clause' => array( 
            'key' => 'custom_author_name',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'           
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that if the meta key `custom_author_name` is set and then unset, that `meta_key` will respond to `EXISTS` and the effect will be that those will be bubbled up alongside posts that do have a `custom_author_name`. In my case I have a checkbox so I'm using `"value" => "1"` instead of `EXISTS`, but strings will need a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually how it works.

If you want to do that without adding table rows, you'll have to do two queries. One with the meta_key that has the limited results, and the other that gets the whole list; then use PHP to compare the two query results (possibly removing the meta_key results from the other query to remove duplicates, or whatever makes sense in your setting).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that isn't how `WP_Query` works. As soon as you add that "meta" component, you've created a kind of filter. Dump `$query->request` and you will see what I mean.

Second, `WP_Query` doesn't support ordering by a meta *key* at all. You can order by a meta *value* for a particular key but no by the key itself. Again, dump the query to see what I mean. You will notice that the "order" components drop out if you try.

The cleanest way to get this to work, in my opinion, is a couple of short filters:

```
function join_meta_wpse_188287($join) {
  remove_filter('posts_join','join_meta_wpse_188287');
  global $wpdb;
  return ' INNER JOIN '.$wpdb->postmeta.' ON ('.$wpdb->posts.'.ID = '.$wpdb->postmeta.'.post_id)';
}
add_filter('posts_join','join_meta_wpse_188287');

function orderby_meta_wpse_188287($orderby) {
  remove_filter('posts_orderby','orderby_meta_wpse_188287');
  global $wpdb;
  return $wpdb->postmeta.'.meta_key ASC';
}
add_filter('posts_orderby','orderby_meta_wpse_188287');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'post_per_page'=>-1
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($q->request); // debug
var_dump(wp_list_pluck($q->posts,'post_title')); // debug
```