# How can I use order_by to order by two meta_keys without excluding posts that don't have those keys initialized?

Tags: wp-query, custom-field

I have two meta_keys on a custom post type. I want to be able to query all of these posts, and order them by the two `meta_key`, one taking precedence over the other.

I.e. I have one `meta_key` called `stickied`, these should always appear first. The second `meta_key` is `popularity`, which is a basic hit count for that post.

When I use `meta_query`, it seems that posts *without* the meta keys initialized will not appear in the result set. I want *all* posts regardless of whether they have the `meta_key` initialized or not, and *then* order them based on those `meta_key`.

Is this possible?

Comment: the meta query is, as you suspect, limiting the posts returned. I believe its actually doing an `INNER JOIN` between the `wp_posts` and `wp_postsmeta` tables where the IDs match `AND` the `meta_key` exists. If you `var_export()` the query you can see it, and the `orderby` applied at the end. I suppose you could force a `popularity` and/or `stickied` default value(s) at post creation though; a `0` and `false`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue but couldn't solved with the snippets on this thread.

I had to order a query by:

1. all 'featured' posts first (***is_it_a_featured_etf***) and
2. by a numeric field (***etf_aum***) in DESC order after the featured ones.

My solution:

```
'meta_query'   => [
  'relation'    => 'OR',

  'etf_aum'    => array(
    'key'     => 'etf_aum',
    'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
  ),

  'is_it_a_featured_etf' => array(
    'key'       => 'is_it_a_featured_etf',
    'compare'   => 'EXISTS',
    'value'     => '1',
    'operator'  => '=',
  ),
],
'orderby' => [
  'is_it_a_featured_etf' => 'ASC',
  'etf_aum' => 'DESC',
]
```

Comment: nice! what were these two keys etf_aum and is_it_a_featured_etf set by?

Comment: **etf_aum** is just a numeric filed. **is_it_a_featured_etf** is a true/false ACF

Comment: thanks, did you set them with code?

Comment: just the numeric field, using `update_post_meta`. The featured flag is edited directly on the post edit page (AFC checkbox meta).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to sort the post by meta values. In such cases, you can use `'orderby => 'meta_value'`. So your query will look like this:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'  => 'stickied',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Not that `orderby` can accept multiple values, such as:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby'   => array( 'title' => 'DESC', 'meta_value' => 'ASC' ),
    'meta_key'  => 'stickied',

);
```

However I'm not sure if you can use multiple meta values, but it is probably possible. At the moment I don't have such condition in my database to test it, but based on my example and this [codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) you should be able to easily try it out.

Please let me know if sorting by multiple values worked for you based on above structure.

### UPDATE

After digging for a while, I've found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188305/94498) answer and this code that provides a solution to this situation:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'meta_key',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( 
            'key'=>'stickied',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'           
        ),
        array( 
            'key'=>'popularity',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'           
        )
    ),
    'post_per_page'=>-1
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: As I read it, OP wants all posts of some type, even those without meta key(s), and only to order by those meta keys as first and second priority, then the rest. If I understand it, `meta_key => some_key` is handled by WP Meta_Query and excludes posts without that key(s), right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I would assume it will also include the posts that do not have a key too, the same way that sorting by title also includes the posts that do not have a title.

Comment: Also [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/28409/94498) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/102447/94498) question are discussing something similar.

Comment: Yes, I want all records regardless of whether the post meta exists or not. No matter how I slice it with meta_query, I either end up with all posts that have meta, or all posts that don't have meta, which isn't what I wanted. I wanted all posts no matter what, and then order the results by meta, putting records without meta last. I ended up writing a function that simply ensures all posts *have* meta, and set initial popularity to 0 and stickied to 0. *Then* am I able to order the results correctly using meta_query and orderby with two meta keys.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to go about solving something like this. The real problem comes if/when you need to apply default pagination to the query.

The best way to handle this, and preserve the ability to paginate, would be to use a combination of meta_query clauses. Jack Johansson was on the right track, this just requires a bit more logic in the query. You may need to adjust the exact combination a bit to suit your needs, as this is just an estimated guess based on the info provided.

Try something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'sticky_pop_clause' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'sp_sticky' => array( 
                'key' => 'stickied',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS' 
            ),
            'sp_pop' => array( 
                'key' => 'popularity',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'           
            )     
        ),
        'sticky_clause' => array( 
            'key' => 'stickied',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'           
        ),
        'popular_clause' => array( 
            'key'=>'popularity',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'           
        ),
        'other_clause' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array( 
                'key'=>'stickied',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'           
            ),
            array( 
                'key'=>'popularity',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'           
            )
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'sp_pop' => 'DESC',
        'sticky_clause' => 'ASC',
        'popular_clause' => 'DESC',
        'date' => 'DESC'
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check all (*select*) the posts with and without `stickied` and `popularity` with both `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`. After that you sort it with `orderby`.

Didn't test it. Modify it to your needs. I did smth similar. Results were okay.

```
$args = [
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'with_stickied' => [
            'key'=>'stickied',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'           
        ],
        'without_stickied' => [
            'key'=>'stickied',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'           
        ],
        'with_popularity' => [
            'key'=>'popularity',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'           
        ],
        'with_popularity' => [
            'key'=>'popularity',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'           
        ],
    ],
    'orderby' => [
            'with_stickied' => 'DESC',
            'with_popularity' => 'DESC',
    ]
];
```

You might want to check "**‘orderby’ with multiple ‘meta_key’s**" from [WP Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters).